# Solve ODE transformed into q-difference in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, difference-equations

Let's take a simple differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -x(t)$

Suppose we want to do a q-transform. To do this, we will replace the time derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$ with the q-derivative (also known as the Jackson's derivative: [q-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-derivative)).

$\frac{x(q \cdot t) - x(t)}{q \cdot t - t} = -x(t)$

**Question**: how to solve the resulting equation in Mathematica?

Comment: Check documentation page for `RSolve`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, `RSolve` does not give the correct answer. The solution does not match the original equation. The point is that the q-analog is not a recurrent equation.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the fact is that the solutions do not match (even with q values close to 1)

Comment: Run the following sequence to compare: `ff0 = RSolveValue[{x[q*t] - x[t] == (q*t - t)*(-x[t]), x[1] == 2}, 
  x[t], t]
ffq = ff /. q -> 101/100
N[Table[ffq, {t, 1., 2., .1}]]
Table[2*Exp[1 - t], {t, 1., 2., .1}]` The two tables give very close values.